# An involute of a shortest path in a strictly convex surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry, metric-geometry

Consider a smooth closed surface $\Sigma$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of positive Gaussian curvature, homeomorphic to a sphere. Here $U$ is the interior of the convex hull of $\Sigma$. When $c:[0,l]\rightarrow \Sigma$ is a minimizing geodesic of unit speed in it, then we defines $$a :[0,l]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3,\ a(t)=c(t)-t c'(t)$$ and $$f(t)=d(x,a(t))$$ for any fixed $x\in \Sigma$. Here $d$ is the intrinsic distance on $ \mathbb{R}^3- U$.

> **Problem :** Then prove that $f(t)$ is increasing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By closed surface I guess you mean an immersed compact submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ without boundary. It is well known that such a surface is the boundary of a strictly convex set of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I'm right ?

Comment: Yes, two things are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a point $x$ And if $c$ is a minimizing geodesic in $\Sigma$, we define $a(t)=c(t)-tc'(t)$ and $f(t)=d(x,a(t))$. We define $b$ s.t. $$\bigg\langle
 a(t+\varepsilon ),\frac{-c''(t)
}{|c''(t) |}  \bigg\rangle \frac{-c''(t) }{|c''(t) | } + a(t)=
b(\varepsilon )$$

If $\gamma=\gamma_\varepsilon$ is a shortest path from $x$ to
$b(\varepsilon)$, then assume that $$ \gamma(0)=x,\ \gamma(s)=y $$
and $$ y\in T_{c(t)}\Sigma \bigcap \gamma $$

Hence by Earnie060's answer, we have $$ f(t) = {\rm length}\ \gamma_0\leq {\rm length} \bigg(
\gamma|[0,s]\cap [y a(t)] \bigg)\leq {\rm length } \gamma $$

Hence $$\frac{d}{d\varepsilon }{\rm length}\ \gamma\geq 0 $$

Further note that
$$|f(t+\varepsilon )- {\rm length}\ \gamma |<C\varepsilon^2$$ for some $C>0$ and some $0<
\varepsilon <\delta$.

Hence $$ \frac{d}{d \varepsilon } f(t+\varepsilon ) = \frac{d}{dt}
{\rm length}\ \gamma $$

which completes the proof.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** the current answer only shows that the distance function on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is increasing. The OP wants to show that the distance on $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus U$ is increasing.

Let $g(t)$ be the squared distance $\langle x - a(t), x-a(t) \rangle$. Its derivative is
$$
\begin{align*}
 g'(t) &= 2 \langle x - c(t) + tc'(t), - c'(t) + c'(t) + tc''(t) \rangle \\
       &= 2 t\langle x - c(t) + tc'(t), c''(t) \rangle \\
       &= 2 t \langle x - c(t), c''(t) \rangle.
\end{align*}
$$
In the last step we used that $\langle c'(t), c''(t) \rangle = 0$ since $c$ has unit speed.

Since $c(t)$ is a geodesic, the acceleration vector $c''(t)$ is parallel with the surface normal of $\Sigma$ at $c(t)$. So the tangent plane at $c(t)$ is given by $\langle p - c(t), c''(t)\rangle = 0$. Also note that $c''(t)$ is an inward pointing normal vector at $c(t)$.

Finally, by the convexity of $\Sigma$, all points of $\Sigma$ lie on one part the tangent plane. Since $c''(t)$ is inward pointing, $\langle x - c(t), c''(t)\rangle\geq 0 $ and consequently
$$
  g'(t) = 2 t \langle x - c(t), c''(t) \rangle \geq 0.
$$
This proves that the Euclidean distance function is increasing.

Comment: This is good ! And we can not apply this argument when $a(t),\ \Sigma$ are in same side wrt $T_x\Sigma$ ?

Comment: I don't think so. (1) I have no idea how to relate the surface normal at an arbitrary point $x$ with $c''(t)$, and (2) In general, $a(t)$ and $\Sigma$ are not on the same side of $T_x \Sigma$. For instance, let $\Sigma$ be the round sphere, $c(t)$ the equator and $x$ some point on the equator. Then, some points of $a(t)$, which is a circle involute, will not lie on the same of side of T_ \Sigma$.

Comment: If $x$ is orthogonal to the great circle, then all $a(t)$ and the sphere are in same side of $T_x\Sigma$. In this case, how can we prove ?

Comment: In the very specific case where $x$ is the north or south pole, you mean? Well, then $c''(t)$ is a vector that points at the $z$-axis, and it's $z$-component is zero. Also $x-c(t)$ points to the north or south pole $x$, and in particular it always points at the $z$-axis. Thus the inner product of these vectors in always positive. (Sketch a picture, it is much more illuminating then an explanation.)

Comment: Maybe, you skip the fact that the square of distance function $|\ -\ |$ is not inner product ?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't fully understand your question. Do you want an explanation why the square of the distance function $f$ is equal to the inner product of $x-a(t)$ with itself? If that is so, I will add it to my answer. If not, can you then please reformulate your question a bit.

Comment: You proved that the Euclidean distance function is increasing. However, the original question is about the intrinsic distance in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus U$. You can use the same approach: for any $x$, take a length-minimizing curve $\gamma$ connecting it to $a(t)$. The point $p\in Im(\gamma)\cap \overline U$ closest to $a(t)$ determines a straight segment $[p,a(t)]$. Applying the answer above to the point $x=p$ gives that the Euclidean distance of $a(t)$ from $p$ is increasing, but now also the intrinsic distance is increasing (the last piece of $\gamma$ can not be better than a segment).

Comment: @Del Thank you for clarifying this!

Comment: @Del Wouldn't p be t-dependent?

Comment: @Max I was about to mention the same thing. The point $p$ indeed depends on $t$.

Comment: @Del Yes. we have to use Ernie060's result. But how can we use ? Could you elaborate your comment ?